# Как получить список всех администраторов с группы Телеграм на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Как можно получить список всех администраторов с группы Телеграма на aiogram, зная только id группы.

Было бы желательно если возможно получить список администраторов без присутствия бота в группе Телеграм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в Telegram Bot API есть метод [getChatAdministrators](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators), нужно передать только ID чата. Для aiogram это будет выглядеть так:

```py
chat_admins = await bot.get_chat_administrators(12345)
```

P.S. Без присутствия бота в чате это работать не будет (и не должно :))

Answer (score 0):

Решил дополнить ответ выше. Для получения администратора чата нам понадобится:

```
chat_admins = await bot.get_chat_administrators(msg.chat.id)
```

> msg = types.Message

Что бы получить id администратора нам остаётся прописать это:

```
for admins in chat_admins:
    userId = admins.user.id
    await msg.answer(text="{}".format(userId))
```